# Boost converter TPS61040 output voltage higher than expected

Tags: integrated-circuit, dc-dc-converter, boost, texas-instruments

Based on the datasheet of [TPS61040](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61041.pdf), the output voltage of this boost converter is

$$V_{out} = 1.233V (1+\frac{R_1}{R_2})$$

<sub>Picture edited to show output capacitor</sub>

[image: TPS61040]

The input voltage is from USB which is 4.9V.

Based on this calculation, for my circuit the output voltage should be 8.118V.
However in practice the ouptu voltage is 14.6V.

How is this possible?

Comment: Don't you have an output capacitor?

Comment: @sai, the output capacitor is after the diode. it is 47u.

Comment: Then. Andy's answer is most probable cause of the issue

Answer (score 5):

> *How is this possible?*

You have the feedback potential divider in the wrong place. It should be like this: -

[image]

I've circled the diode to show that it has moved. You also need an output capacitor.

Comment: How does it make such a difference?

Comment: Maybe you don't understand how boost converters work @barej? I guess you don't so, a better thing would be to ask how boost converters work and raise it as a brand new question. Then, you'd realize that the voltage on the SW pin is a duty cycle modulated square wave and wholly unsuitable as a feedback node point.